# two times square in distance calculation on one example?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, mathematical-statistics, distance, kernel-trick

I read a book on Kernels, See the following example. Why the authors take square two times here? what is the logic?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo, the kernel is
$$K(x_1,x_2)=\exp\left(-||x_1-x_2||^2 \over 2\sigma^2\right)$$

Note that if you do the calculation w/o squaring again, the result rounded upto two digits will be the same.